# HCatalog & Impala itegration

Tags: cloudera, impala, hcatalog

Is there a way to use WebHcat to submit Impala queries?
As far as I understand, Impala uses same metastore as Hive and HCatalog give unified access to this metastore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Impala queries are submitted to a different service endpoint than Hive queries, so you can't use WebHCat to submit queries to Impala.

If you're curious, here's a bit more information about how to submit queries to Impala. First, read the [Impala Concepts and Architecture](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_concepts.html) documentation. As you now know, you can submit your query to any node running the impalad daemon. The interface exposed by this daemon is specified in [ImpalaService.thrift](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/master/common/thrift/ImpalaService.thrift). There are a number of open source clients that have been implemented that will allow you to submit queries to Impala from the command line, from a web interface, or from a library in your favorite programming language. Here are a few examples:

- [impala-shell](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/tree/master/shell): command-line interface that ships with Impala
- [Impala app in Cloudera Hue](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/impala): web interface
- [impyla](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla): Python library
- [impala-ruby](https://github.com/colinmarc/impala-ruby): Ruby library
- [php-impala](https://github.com/RJMetrics/php-impala): PHP library
- [ImpalaSharp](https://github.com/tckz/ImpalaSharp): C# library
- [impala-java-client](https://github.com/pauldeschacht/impala-java-client): Java library